# Remove all elements before x from an array php

Tags: php, arrays

if I give you:

```
$array = array(object1, object2, object3, object4);
```

and say, at position 2, remove all elements before this position so the end result is:

```
$array = array(object3, object4);
```

What would I do? I was looking at [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) and [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) to achieve what I wanted - how ever I am not sure which to use or how to use them to achieve the desired affect.

Comment: array_slice($array,$position);

Comment: @kyle, Do you need to do this based on the item's index or you are looking into the values? and by object do you rely mean an object ($object1, $object2, ... ) or it just an example and you meant 'object1', 'object2', etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_slice. For more detail check link http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

```
$array = array(object1, object2, object3, object4);
$array = array_slice($array,2); // 2 is position
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_slice` is one way to go about it, however, if you are wanting to remove all the elements in an any array before a specific *value*, without searching, then:

```
//assuming you've already verified the match is in the array
//make a copy of $array first if you don't want to break the original
while($array[0] !== $match) {
   array_shift(&$array);
}
```

Alternatively, you could:

```
$index = array_search($match, array_values($array));
if($index !== false) $array = array_slice($array, $index);
```

This accomplished both the verification and slice. Note the array_values() is used to account for associative arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you are looking into the values instead of the index, with a tiny adjustment in @Ashwani's answer you can have:

```
$array = array('object1', 'object2', 'object3', 'object4');
$slice = array_slice($array, array_search('object3',$array));
```